# Does AsyncDisplayKit have an alternative for viewForHeaderInSection?

Tags: ios, swift, asyncdisplaykit

I'm converting an existing app into `AsyncDisplayKit/Texture`. I just converted a `UITableView` to an `ASTableNode`, however, the `UITableView` relies upon `viewForHeaderInSection`. However, I was unable to find a delegate method in `AsyncDisplayKit`'s `ASTableDelegate`.

Is there an alternative to this method? Or should I start looking for a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we haven't it. 
I'm use default UIView classes instead:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     static NSString *header = @"";
     UITableViewHeaderFooterView *vHeader;

     vHeader = [tableView   dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:header];
     if (!vHeader) {
         vHeader = [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:header];
         vHeader.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
         vHeader.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14];
         vHeader.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor tc_blueyGreyColor];
         vHeader.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
     }
     vHeader.textLabel.text = [self.viewModel titleForHeaderInSection:section];
     return vHeader;
}
```

But you can try call `view` property in ASDisplayNode too.

Comment: Would the implementation of `ASTableDelegate` be good here, or do you have to access the underlying `UITableView` and set a delegate on that?

Comment: @ilikecode yes it would be better, it's not just proxy, its have itself methods for ASTableNode. And forget about UITableVIew and it's delegates too.

Comment: But when I just implement `ASTableDelegate`, the `viewForHeaderInSection ` method never gets called?

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section must return >0